# Does AWS Fargate only scale through adding AWS auto scaling to it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm planning on shifting from EC2 to Fargate because it said it automatically "removes the need to choose server types, decide when to scale your clusters, or optimize cluster packing". I think I understand how a cluster scales through auto-scaling rules, but that isn't exactly automatic. So am I missing something regarding how scaling in AWS Fargate works?

As far as I understand so far, I make a basic task. I assign the task some memory and CPU, and the only way it scales is through auto scaling which will basically recreate these tasks when the need arises (either through alarms or specific rules). TIA!

Answer (score 2):

Fargate abstracts underline cluster nodes. In ECS (EC2 instances) you have to manage auto scaling for services and cluster both.

In fargate however you can scale services only and don't have to worry about underline cluster. Very much like service autoscaling you have been doing in ECS.